# Looping a dataframe deleting process in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops, purrr

I wonder how to loop my code below to make it more functional and generalizable for other data (the current data is just a toy):

`FIRST`, I select a `study` from `data` using `sample()` and then `filter()` rows of it whose `outcome == outcome_to_remove`. This gives `datat` output.

`SECOND`, I select a `study` from `datat` using `sample()` and then `filter()` rows of it whose `outcome == outcome_to_remove2`. This gives the final output.

Can we possibly loop this process?

**EDIT:** The only conditional I would like to add to my code is that the `length(unique(data$study))` before and after the looping should always remain the same. That is, it shouldn't be possible that a `study` looses its `outcome == "A"` in the `FIRST` step, and `outcome == "B"` at the `SECOND` step, thus the whole study gets deleted.

```
(data <- expand_grid(study = 1:5, group = 1:2, outcome = c("A", "B")))

n = 1
#====-------------------- FIRST:  
studies_to_remove = sample(unique(data$study), size = n)
outcome_to_remove = c("A")
             
datat <- data %>%
  filter(
    !(    study %in% studies_to_remove &
        outcome %in% outcome_to_remove
    ))

#====------------------- SECOND:
studies_to_remove2 = sample(unique(datat$study), size = n)
outcome_to_remove2 = c("B")

datat %>%
  filter(
    !(    study %in% studies_to_remove2 &
        outcome %in% outcome_to_remove2
    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `for` loop -

```
data <- tidyr::expand_grid(study = 1:5, group = 1:2, outcome = c("A", "B"))

n = 1
set.seed(9873)
outcome_to_remove <- unique(data$outcome)
unique_study <- unique(data$study)

for(i in outcome_to_remove) {
  studies_to_remove = sample(unique_study, size = n)
  outcome_to_remove = i
  unique_study <- setdiff(unique_study, studies_to_remove)
  cat('\nDropping study ', studies_to_remove, 'and outcome ', outcome_to_remove)
  data <- data %>%
    filter(
      !( study %in% studies_to_remove &
         outcome %in% outcome_to_remove
      ))
}

#Dropping study  3 and outcome  A
#Dropping study  1 and outcome  B

data
#   study group outcome
#   <int> <int> <chr>  
# 1     1     1 A      
# 2     1     2 A      
# 3     2     1 A      
# 4     2     1 B      
# 5     2     2 A      
# 6     2     2 B      
# 7     3     1 B      
# 8     3     2 B      
# 9     4     1 A      
#10     4     1 B      
#11     4     2 A      
#12     4     2 B      
#13     5     1 A      
#14     5     1 B      
#15     5     2 A      
#16     5     2 B
```

Comment: 1. My code does exactly what you have shown in your question but with a loop. The only difference being you have used a new variable (`datat`) but I have used the same variable (`data`). 2. Your code does not remove the study completely. If you remove `outcome = 'A'` for a study but `outcome = 'B'` is still present for the same study in `datat`. My code works the same way.

Comment: @rnorouzian Then you need to change your question accordingly. Your question does not reflect what you actually want to do. Using the same code from your question it is also possible that the entire study is dropped from the output.